# Design a single page website with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my psuedo-code for a Single page website I am doing. I need to be able to make a single page website that is not scroll-based (which is the typical). The idea here is that my site have a `nav` where user selects a menu and depending on the selected menu the correct page div is rendered on the content div.

The `page divs` are also in the HTML and should not be displayed unless the correct menu is selected (or if a better approach is to place the pages in Javascript file):

```
<nav>
 <ul>
   <li>menu1</li>
   <li>menu2</li>
 </ul>
</nav>

<div id="content">
  <!-- content will be from page divs below -->
</content>

<div id="page1"> <!-- for menu1 -->
 <div>the content</div>
</div>

<div id="page2"> <!-- for menu2 -->
 <div>the content</div>
</div>
```

How can achieve this with jQuery?

Comment: And the question is ?

Comment: You could use ajax to load different content on a single page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you looking for

Html :-

```
<nav>
    <ul>
    <li class="nav active" data-id="1">menu1</li>
    <li class="nav" data-id="2">menu2</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="content">
    <!-- content will be from page divs below -->
    <div id="page1" class="page">
    <!-- for menu1 -->
    <div>the content from page 1</div>
    </div>
    <div id="page2" class="hide page">
    <!-- for menu2 -->
    <div>the content from page2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.nav').click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        $('.page').hide();
        var clickedId = $(this).data('id');
        $('#page' + clickedId).show();
    });


});
```

<kbd>[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfjGF/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

To display preloaded contents in different containers you can use anchor tag with some CSS

**HTML**

```
<a href="#page1">a</a>
<a href="#page2">b</a>
<a href="#page3">c</a>

<div id="page1" class="page"> this is page1 id</div>
<div id="page2" class="page"> this is page2 id</div>
<div id="page3" class="page"> this is page3 id</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#page1, #page2, #page3{
    display:none;
}
#page1:target{
    display:block;
}
#page2:target{
    display:block;
}
#page3:target{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As another answer stated, you may want to take a look at [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org). Here is an excellent tutorial to get you started if you choose: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM

However, since your question stated jQuery, the best way will probably be to have all the pages separate html pages that are loaded in via AJAX and replace your current html.

The other approach is to have everything on the page at once and hide and show the content based on the menu item the user clicked.  However, this may make the page REALLY sluggish if you have a lot of content all on the page at once.

Comment: how does one show content from different html pages when clicking the menu?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the content to be embedded in the page but hidden, use jQuery's .hide() and .show()

If you want to keep the content in separate pages, use jQuery's .load()

Answer (score 0):

use this code , make sure your `#page1` and `#page2` divs hidden initially

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){

     jQuery('li').click(function(){

        var new_index = parseInt(jQuery(this).index())+1;

        jQuery("div[id*='page']").hide();
        jQuery('#page'+new_index).show();

     });
  });


<nav>
 <ul>
   <li>menu1</li>
   <li>menu2</li>
 </ul>
</nav>

<div id="content">
  <!-- content will be from page divs below -->
</content>

<div id="page1" style="display:none";> <!-- for menu1 -->
 <div>the content 1</div>
</div>

<div id="page2" style="display:none";> <!-- for menu2 -->
 <div>the content 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this link, it will help you. you are having navigation bar on your right hand site from where you can navigate through out your website.

[Single page website](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html)